# javascript unique distinct color generator for new users in a chat application

Tags: javascript, colors

I want to adapt something like this:

http://blog.adamcole.ca/2011/11/simple-javascript-rainbow-color.html

But for a chat application where each new user gets a new most distinct color.

Everytime a user enters my chat application my server responds with a new incremental number. (This code works fine).

So the first user gets a zero, the second a one etc.

I want to take this number and match it to a most unique color.

Thanks for any help.

Below is the code from the link

```
 function rainbow(numOfSteps, step) {
 // This function generates vibrant, "evenly spaced" colours (i.e. no   clustering). This is ideal for creating easily distinguishable vibrant  markers in Google Maps and other apps.
 // Adam Cole, 2011-Sept-14
 // HSV to RBG adapted from: http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript
 var r, g, b;
 var h = step / numOfSteps;
 var i = ~~(h * 6);
 var f = h * 6 - i;
 var q = 1 - f;
 switch(i % 6){
    case 0: r = 1, g = f, b = 0; break;
    case 1: r = q, g = 1, b = 0; break;
    case 2: r = 0, g = 1, b = f; break;
    case 3: r = 0, g = q, b = 1; break;
    case 4: r = f, g = 0, b = 1; break;
    case 5: r = 1, g = 0, b = q; break;
 }
 var c = "#" + ("00" + (~ ~(r * 255)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("00" + (~ ~(g * 255)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("00" + (~ ~(b * 255)).toString(16)).slice(-2);
return (c);
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the source code you want to edit to add the changes? Should we guess how your chat application works to implement the new source code??

Comment: I have added the code from the link. I just want a function that takes a number and returns a color. The difference with the code that exists is there is not a predefined number of steps, each new user will get a new number for ever.

Comment: Do the displayed colors absolutely need to remain consistent between different instances of the application? Otherwise you could assign random colors as people enter the chat.

Comment: I updated my answer to use random generation as in @Thriggle 's recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the best I'll be able to do for you. I use the rainbow method you provided. I create an array of colors. I shuffle the array. As a new user joins, I pop a value from the array. You can handle the logic of creating new arrays if you exceed your limit. For example, as a user leaves, you could append their color back onto the array or prepend it to the front like a queue.

```js
function rainbow(numOfSteps, step) {
  var r, g, b;
  var h = step / numOfSteps;
  var i = ~~(h * 6);
  var f = h * 6 - i;
  var q = 1 - f;
  switch(i % 6){
    case 0: r = 1, g = f, b = 0; break;
    case 1: r = q, g = 1, b = 0; break;
    case 2: r = 0, g = 1, b = f; break;
    case 3: r = 0, g = q, b = 1; break;
    case 4: r = f, g = 0, b = 1; break;
    case 5: r = 1, g = 0, b = q; break;
  }
  var c = "#" + ("00" + (~ ~(r * 255)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("00" + (~ ~(g * 255)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("00" + (~ ~(b * 255)).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  return (c);
}

//fisher-yates shuffle:
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

//create a number of random colors:
var steps = 100;
var colors = [];
for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
  colors.push(rainbow(steps, i));
}
shuffleArray(colors);


function newUser() {
  var color = colors.pop();
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.display = "inline-block";
  div.style.width = "10px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = color;
  div.innerHTML = "u";
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newUser();">add new user</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - in the end I generated rgb values on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The code example below takes any number up to 16777215 and displays a color. The major downside to using the user numbers that you're generating incrementally is that the color generated for each number is only slightly different from the preceding number, which wouldn't be ideal for distinguishing users from each other.

If you don't need the generated color to be reproducible or consistent across visitors, I'd recommend randomly generating a number (as below) instead of deriving it from the user's number.

```js
document.getElementById("input").value = ((16777215 * Math.random()) % 16777215) >>> 0;
(function() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  input.onkeyup = updateDiv;

  function updateDiv() {
    var num = (+(input.value)).toString(16); // obtain hex code for color
    var comp = (0xffffff ^ +(input.value)).toString(16); // obtain complement of the color to make sure text is visible
    while (num.length < 6) {
      num = "" + "0" + num;
    }
    while (comp.length < 6) {
      comp = "" + "0" + comp;
    }
    output.innerHTML = "" + num;
    output.style.backgroundColor = "#" + num;
    output.style.color = "#" + comp;
  }
  updateDiv();
})();
document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = parseInt(0xffffff, 10);
```

```css
#output {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
<div id="output">&nbsp;</div>max color:
<div id="max" />
```

Comment: If I randomly generate a number using the users id as a seed, will this result in the same colours for a user in different clients browsers?

Comment: If you were using your own random number generator, then yes! Unfortunately, JavaScript's `Math.random()` random number generator does not accept a seed.